# how to replace double quotes inside the string in perl

Tags: perl, double-quotes

want to replace the apostrophes into double quotes in perl

**Example**

```
'It's raining'
```

**Print**

```
'It"s raining'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a backslash to quote the quote:

```
print "I think \"it's raining\" if you know what I mean\n";
```

However, a better way is to get use to using the [quote-like](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) operators `qq( ... )` for double quotes and `q( .. )` for single quotes:

```
print qq(I think "it's raining" if you know what I mean\n);
```

The parentheses can be almost any character, just like the substitution or regular expression match:

```
print qq/I think "it's raining" if you know what I mean\n/;
print qq#I think "it's raining" if you know what I mean\n#;
```

The nice thing about parentheses is that they must match:

```
print qq(I think "it's raining" if you know what I mean (he said with a wink)\n);
```

That still works.

---

## Now the correct answer

> I am using the Syntax str_replace( string_expr1, string_expr2, string_expr3 ) –  user3548698

So, you're not *escaping*, you're replacing:

Use the `s/.../.../` operator:

```
my $string = "it's raining";
my $string =~ s/'/"/g;   # The `g` means all instances
print "$string\n";       # Prints it"s raining.
```

Comment: i am using the Syntax str_replace( string_expr1, string_expr2, string_expr3 )

Comment: So, this isn't about _escaping_ the quotes (what you had as your tag)?

Comment: See my appended answer above.

Comment: s/'/"/g; its not working..str_replace( string_expr1, string_expr2, string_expr3 ) is using in the select statement...my query in the replace syntax str_replace( empname, '''', ~s/'/"/g) not working...

Comment: When you say "its now working", can you provide the code and the errors please.  It would be good if you put this detail in your original question - you can edit it now!

Comment: @user3548698 It looks like this is about a specific issue. You asked a general question and got a general answer. What exactly are you doing? Are you trying to edit a select statement? Are you trying to build one? What is the expected input and output? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use global search and replace, e.g.

```
 $your_string =~ s/'/"/g;
```

It's a lot simpler than any function call and gives access to other great bits of perl!

Adding the g at the end gives global search and replace, so all instances of ' within $your_string will be replaced and not just the first one.